# How to implement proxy for a Wildly project with Apache?

Tags: apache, wildfly, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I've implemented a JavaEE project with JSF and deployed into my local Wildly server. Right now I'm perfectly ok and I can access it with any browser by typing http://localhost:8080/gestionale/. Right now I want to move the project to the cloud in a Linux machine. The idea is to setup Apache with SSL/TLS with Let's Encrypt in order to encrypt all the data, but I'm not sue how to implement this in the Apache server configuration. May this work?

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com 
ProxyPass                   /       http://127.0.0.1:8080/gestionale/ 
ProxyPassReverse            /       http://127.0.0.1:8080/gestionale/  

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile privkey.pem
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The idea is access the JSF project by using mydomain.com directly: is this possible? Does all the data exchanged TLS/SSL secured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your life easier by starting with unencrypted.  A basic configuration would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.tld

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gestionale/
    ProxyTimeout 360
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, install [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) and run the what the instructions tell you to.  For example, on Ubuntu you'd run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache 
sudo certbot --apache
```

Certbot will update your Apache SSL configuration for you.  It will also ask you if you want to setup redirection from HTTP to HTTPS (a generally good idea).

Make sure that your domain name resolves correctly in DNS or you won't be able to correctly run certbot.  That's the advantage of HTTP only at first to validate that everything is setup correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Will CSS, JS, resources be loaded correctly? Should I do some edits in Wildfly? Once done with Let’Encrypt, should I implement manually a reditect?

Comment: Everything should be behind Apache.  You won't have to make any changes to Wildfly and Certbot / Lets Encrypt will make the redirect changes for you if you'd like.  There will be a place during the setup that you get to decide.